# Linux ''find'' command: File aging for special extention. Regex and mtime doesn't work together

Tags: regex, linux, shell, find, filemtime

My .sh file is like below:

```
#!/bin/sh

FOLDER = '/home/Desktop/myUserName/My_monitored_folder'

ASD= 'cd $FOLDER'
REGEX = '.*xxx.yyy*.*'
$ASD
CMD = 'find -regextype posix-extended -regex $REGEX -mtime +0h10m0s'
$CMD | xargs ls -Blatr**
```

My find version is: `4.4.2`

when I run this shell file:
my purpose is to get some type of files(regex is just for that) that aged in that folder older than 10 minutes.
Funny thing is that, `-regex` without `-mtime` give me back the files I need. When I use them together, it ends up in `ls -Blatr`

`mtime` doesn't function well. indeed `mtime` doesn't function at all. 
Could anyone take a look at it? I might be missing something
thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Is this working code?

Comment: My version of `find` indicates that the argument to `-mtime` is a simple number with a granularity of days... Granted, it's a bit of an older system. What version of `find` are you using?

Comment: Does `man find` tell you that `+0h10m0s` is a valid syntax for `-mtime`? It doesn't on my Debian Wheezy system that also has GNU `find` v4.4.2...

Comment: Sorry for late response, anubhava, works on ubuntu and solaris nicely, only thing is it is not "mtime" but "mmin". my latest code is below. @twalberg, I saw couple usages online. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
OPENDIRECTORY='//My_Monitored_Folder'
REGEXTYPE='posix-extended'
REGEX='.*xxx.yyy*.*'
MINUTESAGED='+15'
CMD="find -regextype $REGEXTYPE -regex $REGEX -mmin $MINUTESAGED"
$OPENDIRECTORY
$CMD | xargs ls -lrt | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f6-9
```

last pipes are to just get name and time from terminal log. 
I hope it helps everyone looking for this subject

Answer (score 0):

Without some sample filenames, I cannot directly reproduce the issue but one possible workaround is to leave the regex business to `grep`.

```
find --mtime +0h10m0s | egrep $REGEX | xargs ...
```